# How to export library to Jar which include some jcenter library like this compile 'com.lzy.net:okgo:3.0.4'

Tags: android, android-studio

```
task makeJar(type: Copy) {
delete 'build/libs/ble_sdk.jar'
from('build/intermediates/bundles/release/')
into('build/libs/')
include('classes.jar')
rename('classes.jar', 'ble_sdk.jar')
}

makeJar.dependsOn(build)
```

and i want to include some jcenter libraries   how to Embedded them？？ help